# Google Maps prevent attack to force multiple requests

Tags: javascript, google-maps, security, google-maps-api-3, javascript-security

Recently Google Maps [has updated its prices](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/important-updates) and it makes me wonder what happen if a malicious user decides to visit a website with a Google Map, open the developer console of the browser and write a loop which makes requests to google maps using the key of the visited website.

I guess Google Maps will see these requests as legitimate because they come from the domain associated with the key, so this requests will count for the billing.

Am I right? How we can prevent this attack?

Comment: you could proxy the request to your server which holds the api key, then debounce it on the server. the client would then not be able to make an undebounced, authenticated request

Comment: Google uses already a way to minimize this "attacks", exactly I don't know how it works and someone can explain it better that's why I write a comment, the way Google do it is like ignoring extra requests from an specific IP (I guess, Idk) if an IP sends 5000 requests in 15minutes it counts like 5.

Comment: Why this question has been marked to be closed?

Comment: Close votes come with an explanation.